# Hierarchical Object Design (Java)

Tags: oop

I am looking for an elegant design for a problem analogous to the following:

A story can have a flexible hierarchical structure. It might consist of several books, each of which have chapters, each of which have sections, each of which contain text. Or, it might simply have sections (a short story for instance). Or it might just consist of chapters that have sections. In all situations, you mustn't be allowed to mix styles (so you couldn't add a chapter to a story based on books, you would have to add the chapter to the book itself).

I have come up with a couple of design solutions for this type of problem but they get messy. Is there a clean way to represent this so that, given a reference to a Story class I can get access to the content in a clear, systematic fashion?

Comment: Think: a small number of common interfaces, and concrete implementation classes for each different story structure you want to represent.

Comment: Ok it gets tricky now because this was an analogy, not the actual problem! But effectively I had classes equivalent to ChapterBasedStory, SectionBasedStory, BookBasedStory, ChapterBasedBook, SectionBasedBook and so on. It got really messy with factory methods for and/or lots of tests of the contained type. Maybe that mess is unavoidable!? Hence my question :)

Comment: Interesting, I updated my answer based on your comments (see last paragraph). I'd recommend taking a look at the Composite pattern.

Comment: The Composite pattern almost works. The problem is that there is not a lot stopping me (say) adding Books to chapters via an addChild( Element el ) method. Composite allows me to create arbitrary hierarchies, not the specific sort I'm dealing with here.

Comment: @Matt Ball, actually its the opposite: "In all situations, you mustn't be allowed to mix styles". Interfaces allow to treat different classes to "mix" similar elements from different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Its kind of tricky situation because the concepts like "Books", "chapters", "sections", may have some common elements that suggest a class hierarchy or common interface implementation.*

*And at the same time, enough different to be handle as different classes / objects, at all, as the requirement of "so you couldn't add a chapter to a story based on books".*

When dealing conceptualy with hierarchical objects, there are several approaches of how to turn them into into code, each one suits better to a particular situation.

**1. Class Composition**

There is a class or prototype for each concept, they may be related or not by inheritance or interfaces.
There are internal collections of the elements, and their operations can be restricted,
by methods.

```
// this one can be optional, not required,
// replaced by several parent classes,
// or replaced by interfaces

public class LibraryRootClassMaybe {
  // members here
}

public class BookText extends LibraryRootClassMaybe {
  // members here
} // class BookText

public class BookSection extends LibraryRootClassMaybe {
    // element collection should not be public
  List BookTexts;

  public Book() {
    this.BookTexts = new ArrayList();
  }

  public void addBookTest(BookText Item) {
    // validation and casting from object to BookText
  }

  // members here
} // class BookSection

public class BookChapter extends LibraryRootClassMaybe {
    // element collection should not be public
  List BookSections;

  public Book() {
    this.BookSections = new ArrayList();
  }

  public void addBookTest(BookSection Item) {
    // validation and casting from object to BookSection
  }

  // members here
} // class BookChapter

public class Book extends LibraryRootClassMaybe {
    // element collection should not be public
  List BookChapters;

  public Book() {
    this.BookChapters = new ArrayList();
  }

  public void addBookTest(BookText Item) {
    // validation and casting from object to BookText
  }

  // members here
} // class Book
```

These approach is good when there are not many different classes, maybe 5.

**2. The Tree Design Pattern.**

These one applies when all elements will be equal if not similar,
usually same class or interface, usually a lot of items.

These one does not apply to your case, but, 
I had to mention, to apply better.

Usually, a tree / hierarchical collection class, its used.
It could be a subclass of a generic / template tree collection,
or a subclass of a base tre collection,
that is intended to be replaced by child classes with particular members.

```
public class FileSystemRootClass {

  public bool AmISystemRoot() {
    // more
  }

  public bool AmIAFolder() {
    // more
  }

  public bool AmIAFile() {
    // more
  }

  public void addSystemRoot(string FileSystemName) {
    // more
  }

  public void addFolder(string FileSystemName) {
    // more
  }

  public void addFile(string FileSystemName) {
    // more
  }

  // members here
}
```

**3. The Hybrid.**

These one is a combination of the previous two,
its used when there is a lot of related items,
its more complex, may use or not the Factory & Abstract Factory Patterns,
and its more common example are visual controls & widgets libraries.

```
import java.util.*;
public class WidgetsExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet <Widget> FormControls = new TreeSet<Widget>();

    TextBoxWidget TextBox = new TextBoxWidget();
    FormControls.add(TextBoxWidget);

    ListBoxWidget ListBox = new ListBoxWidget();
    FormControls.add(TextBoxWidget);

    ButtonWidget Button = new ButtonWidget();
    FormControls.add(Button);
} // class WidgetsExample
```

You may notice that I didn't use the "factory pattern" & "abstract factory",
due to require more code.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Good OO design starts with thinking about Use Cases and not class hierarchies.  This is a common mistake and tends to produce over-complicated designs.

First consider what you are building and write out a problem statement a description of the problem you are solving using English prose in the language of the problem domain.

Then consider making a mockup if the product is a UI.

Then you can start writing out use cases and start thinking about how objects will interact with each other.

It's called Object-oriented programming, not Class-oriented programming.  Classes are the specification in code to manage/create/run all the objects in the system.  I'd be thinking about objects and what they are doing. Classes are simply an implementation detail.

If your goal is to perform operations on hierarchies, you might want to consider using the Composite pattern.  You could do something like have a Story object that can contain a list of Story objects.  Each Story object would also have it's own type (book-collection,book,chapter,sub-chapter,paragraph,essay), and it's own attributes and methods (depending on your use cases).

Comment: +1 Let the class hierarchy evolve from implementing behavior rather than trying to model the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
interface StoryElement<SE extends SubElements>{
    List<SE> getContents()
}

class Story<T extends StoryElement>


class Book implements StoryElement<Chapter> ...
class Chapter implements StoryElement<Section> ...
class Section implements StoryElement<Text>
class Text implements StoryElement<Text> {... // ugly hack, don't know of a clean way to end the recursion with Java Generics
```

Now you can have a Story of Books or a Story of Text.

Warning: Java Generics tend to fall flat on their face when trying to complex things. In case of doubt, just forget generics and cast.

Comment: Thanks Jens. Unfortunately, doing something like 

class Book implements StoryElement<Chapter>

is the thing I want to avoid, since what happens if I find a book that has no chapters, only sections?

Comment: I think it wouldn't be a book. It would be either a Chapter (when it is contained in a Book or in a Story<Chapter> or it would be a Story<Section>. The whole thing is always a Story. A Book is only a part of a Story.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Might be worth a play. My only slight concern is that Story<Book> and Story<Section> are different types and will require a bit of a fiddle at the top level. Eg if 

Story s = getStory();

then I have to get the type of story.

Comment: Jumps straight to interfaces, too quickly. If the objects share members or elements, then a class hierarchy should be used instead of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the posters. Here is my work-in-progress solution:

```
public abstract class Element
{
    public ElementSet getContent() { return content; }

    // Overrides of setContent() check to see if the content type is appropriate
    // using instanceof.
    public void setContent( ElementSet content )
    {
        this.content = content;
    }


    private ElementSet content;
}

public abstract class ElementSet
{
    protected final void addElement( Element e )
    {
         elements.add(e);
    }

    private final List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
}

public class BookSet extends ElementSet
{
    // Typesafe interface. 
    public void addBook( Book book ) { super.addElement( book ); }
}

public class ChapterSet extends ElementSet { /* similar to BookSet */ }

public class SectionSet extends ElementSet { /* similar to BookSet */ }

public class Book extends Element
{
    @Override
    public void setContent( ElementSet content )
    {
        if ( !(content instanceof ChapterSet) && !(content instanceof SectionSet) )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        super.setContent( content );
    }

    public boolean addChapter( Chapter chapter )
    {
        ElementSet content = getContent();
        if ( content == null )
        {
            content = new ChapterSet();
            setContent( content );
        }
        else if ( !(content instanceof ChapterSet) )
        {
            // Structure is wrong.
            return false;
        }

        ChapterSet chapters = (ChapterSet)content;
        chapters.addChapter( chapter);

        return true;        
    }

    public boolean addSection( Section section )
    {
        ElementSet content = getContent();
        if ( content == null )
        {
            content = new SectionSet();
            super.setContent( content );
        }
        else if ( !(content instanceof SectionSet) )
        {
            // Structure is wrong.
            return false;
        }

        SectionSet sections = (SectionSet)content;
        sections.addSection( section );

        return true;                
    }
}

public class Chapter extends Element
{
    @Override
    public void setContent( ElementSet content )
    {
        if ( !(content instanceof SectionSet) )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        super.setContent( content );
    }

    public boolean addSection( Section section )
    {
        ElementSet content = getContent();
        if ( content == null )
        {
            content = new SectionSet();
            super.setContent( content );
        }
        else if ( !(content instanceof SectionSet) )
        {
            // Structure is wrong.
            return false;
        }

        SectionSet sections = (SectionSet)content;
        sections.addSection( section );

        return true;                
    }
}
```

I tried using generics to achieve the same end, but it looked rather ugly due to need to reflect the parametrised type of a container.